# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure when loading html from url

Tags: java, url, ssl

I have a code that worked perfectly yesterday and today it throws an Exception:
The code WORKS on all other websites I tried..

**The Code:**

```
String line = "", all = "",URL="https://www.website.co.il/";
    URL myUrl = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        myUrl = new URL(URL);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myUrl.openStream(),"UTF-8"));

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            all += line;
            all+='\n';
        }
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            in.close();
        }
    }
```

**The Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
```

Can anyone see the  problem?
could the owners of the website change something that could have make such a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SSL Labs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.racer.co.il) for the the site indicates that it only supports the TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA cipher suite which is not supported by Java. If you look at the handshake simulation section of the report, you will see that handshakes simulated for Java 6, 7 and 8 all fail.

**Edit:** As @Robert has indicated in the comment, installing the Unlimited Strength Policy Files will add support for this cipher suite in Java, enabling your client to communicate with this site.

[image: Supported cipher suites showing only TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]

[image: Handshake simulation for Java clients indicating failure]

Comment: AFAIK Java does not support this cipher because of AES256 - you need to install the [Unlimited Strength Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html), then AES256 is supported and also this cipher.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for the pointer. I've added this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you made a java update?
Java 7 has TLS1 as default and Java 8 has TLS1.2 as default.
You may need to specify manualy the TLS/SSL version.
https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https